# Docker cannot `cd` to volume dir

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

**Objective**:

1. Create a docker volume
2. cd to that volume to check my contents

---

```
$ docker volume create hello_world

$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               hello_world

$ docker inspect hello_world
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-11-19T05:37:03Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello_world/_data",
        "Name": "hello_world",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

$ cd /mnt
bash: cd: /mnt: No such file or directory
```

**IF I cannot cd to the `Mountpoint` then where is it being saved?**

Also tried this

```
$ docker-machine ssh default
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build HEAD : c7e5c3e - Wed Aug 22 16:27:42 UTC 2018
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
docker@default:~$ cd /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello_world/_data
-sh: cd: can't cd to /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello_world/_data
```

---

I am using Windows 8, Docker ToolBox